# Magento upgrade takes too long and never completes

Tags: php, magento

I am upgrading magento from 1.4.0.1 to 1.7.0.2. Initially there were some errors; after fixing those, now the upgrade is running for 5 hours and never completes. No error is displaying. Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: What method do you use to update? The best method is imho to replace all files with the newest Magento, run the setup script again and then re-install the extensions (in the admin, or preferably with version control).

Comment: I am using manual method. adding old files to new magneto, importing old database to new db and then run the application and trying to fix issues. Is there any difference between this and your method?

Comment: In the method you mentioned, when the new version is installed, it will have the new database and thus old records (order, invoice, customer) will be missing.

Comment: I think our methods are the same. I use the old db with my method. You could try to upgrade magento with small version steps. Each version, different queries are executed to update the db. With step by step updating, you will find which version causes the trouble. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I On the query logging by changing the following lines in **lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php** file

```
protected $_debug               = true;
protected $_logAllQueries       = true;
protected $_debugFile           = 'var/debug/pdo_mysql.log';
```

Then by analyzed the **pdo_myql.log** file I came to know that a query is executing with error and thus the magento installer run it again and again.

Error was.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry ''11199-1' for key 'UNQ_INCREMENT_ID'
```

So I deleted the entry in the database table and in **pdo_mysql.log** now other queries are displaying and the up-gradation is complete.

Working many days on magento upgrade, I am summarizing the steps to successfully upgrading magento from 1.4.0.1 to 1.7.0.2. These errors displayed will be different for other projects because every project have different data.

1. Create a **fresh database** for the new version. (I am using
   **SQLyog** because it is good for big database importing and exporting).
2. Extract and Install fresh version 1.7.0.1 in **www** or **htdocs**.
   My project name is **magento171**.
3. Create **new database** because we will need the **fresh db** in **repair step**.
4. Import the **old database** data into the **new database**.
5. Change the **new database** name in **etc/local.xml** in new installed version of magento.
6. In **etc/local.xml** find and change **SET NAMES utf8** to **SET NAMES utf8; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;** .
7. Copy old project file in new version of magento. I have the theme in
   blank folder. Copy default if you have template files in default
   folder.

   • app\design\frontend\default\blank

   • app\code\local

   • skin\frontend\default/blank

   • app\etc\modules (copy the files which are not in the new version).
8. On the MySql queries logging by changing the following lines in 
   **lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\ Mysql.php**

   ```
    protected $_debug               = true;
    protected $_logAllQueries       = true;
    protected $_debugFile           = 'var/debug/pdo_mysql.log';
   ```
9. Search and change
   **CREATE TABLE**  to **CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS**  In code/core/mage/.
10. Change the following entries in the table **core_config_data** (use your
     project folder name).

    ```
      • web/unsecure/base_url | http://localhost/magento171/
      • web/secure/base_url   | http://localhost/magento171/
    ```
11. Rename **/errors/local.xml.sample** to **/errors/local.xml** to enable error_reporting .
12. Clear the magento cache by delete all the data in **var\cache**.
13. Go to browser and type the your project path.
     **http://localhost/magento171/** and keep eyes on the browser and on the **var/debug/pdo_mysql.log** file.
14. The first error occurred to me is: Error in file:
     "D:\xampp\htdocs\magento171\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\sql\sales_setup\mysql4-upgrade-1.3.99-1.4.0.0.php"

    - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7' for key 'PRIMARY'

    Fix: I found from **pdo_mysql.log** file that the issue is in the **sales_flat_order** table, which means many duplicate entries for primary key are there so I truncate all the sales tables. This is actually the error in my old DB. In new version increment_id is UNIQUE. We can't skip primary key checks, so I truncated all the tables related to sales. If you have same issue then truncate all tables related to that feature like if duplicate in customer then truncate all customer table or if in catalog then truncate catalog tables. But remember truncate should be done at the time when the error is occured because if truncated before the installation begins the installer will not read the existing data and finally you will miss some records like missing some orders or invoices.

    ```
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_comment`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_grid`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_item`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_address`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_grid`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_payment`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_status_history`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_payment`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_comment`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_grid`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_item`;
    TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_track`;
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
    ```
15. The installation takes too long, so I inspect the **pdo_mysql.log** file and the following error is displaying again and again. Error displayed: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry ''11199-1' for key 'UNQ_INCREMENT_ID''
    Fix:
    So I delete the first entry in the table.
16. **Database Rapair Step:** It is necessary to Repair the new database with the fresh database using **magento-db-repair-tool-1.1** (http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool). It the end the report will show all the fixes.
17. Now you can simply shift the website to the live server.

Answer (score 9):

I recently upgraded a clients magento  from V1.4 to V1.7.2.0 and i followed this steps:-
Following are the main points to upgrade the website from Magento v1.4.0.0 to v1.7.2.0:-

1. Collect the live database backup in a zipped format, without the following tables:-

   - “log_customer”
   - “log_quote”
   - “log_summary”
   - “log_url”
   - “log_url_info”
   - “log_visitor”
   - “log_visitor_info”

   “log_visitor_online”
2. Unzip the zipped backup database, in your own file system, in any folder.
3. Start the local WAMP / XAMPP, and create a test database “test_something” or any other name, using the web app “phpMyAdmin”.
4. Open the command prompt window and then type “mysql” to start the MySQL Command Prompt.
5. Import the unzipped database into the test database, using the command prompt, so that it will be a lot faster without any errors.
6. After the successful import, run the SQL mentioned in the file “DB Changes.txt” from phpMyAdmin.
7. Extract a fresh Magento v1.7.2.0 in local WAMP / XAMPP, and start installing this Magento using the test database with the old livesite data.
8. After successful Magento installation, export & dump the new upgraded database in a zipped format using command prompt, so that it will be a lot faster without any errors.
9. Extract a fresh zipped Magento or upload a fresh unzipped Magento of v1.7.2.0 into the live server’s file system, without installing anything.
10. Upload this zipped database into the live server’s file system, and then open the PuTTY for the live server.
11. Upload a copy of the “app/etc/local.xml” Magento file of local WAMP / XAMPP, to replace the live Magento’s “app/etc/local.xml” file. Remember to change all the DB credentials of this file, as per the new live server, before uploading it to the live server.
12. Remember not to browse the Magento from the web browser for the live web server, till the point #14 gets completed.
13. Using PuTTY commands, extract the zipped database, and then import it into the new database of the live website.
14. After the successful import, search “core_config_data” database table with the “path” column value as “%base_url%”. Replace all the values of the “value” column with the full URL of the live Site “http://www.livesite.com/”, without any mention of “index.php”.
15. Upload the theme and its related files to the new server’s file system.
16. Upload the extension/module check there compatibility.
17. Make sure to configure the required modules in the System Configuration are from the Admin panel.

    The DB Changes.txt are as follows:-
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_customer` (
      `log_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `visitor_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `login_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `logout_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`),
      KEY `IDX_VISITOR` (`visitor_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Customers log information';

    ---

    --

    ### -- Table structure for table `log_quote`

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_quote` (
      `quote_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `visitor_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`quote_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Quote log data';

    ---

    --

    ### -- Table structure for table `log_summary`

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_summary` (
      `summary_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `type_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `visitor_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `customer_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `add_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      PRIMARY KEY (`summary_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Summary log information';

    ---

    --

    ### -- Table structure for table `log_url`

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_url` (
      `url_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `visitor_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `visit_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      PRIMARY KEY (`url_id`),
      KEY `IDX_VISITOR` (`visitor_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='URL visiting history';

    ---

    --

    ### -- Table structure for table `log_url_info`

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_url_info` (
      `url_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `referer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`url_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Detale information about url visit';

    ---

    --

    ### -- Table structure for table `log_visitor`

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_visitor` (
      `visitor_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `session_id` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `first_visit_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `last_visit_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `last_url_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`visitor_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='System visitors log';

    ---

    --

    ### -- Table structure for table `log_visitor_info`

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_visitor_info` (
      `visitor_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `http_referer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `http_user_agent` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `http_accept_charset` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `http_accept_language` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `server_addr` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `remote_addr` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`visitor_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Additional information by visitor';

    ---

    --

    ### -- Table structure for table `log_visitor_online`

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_visitor_online` (
      `visitor_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `visitor_type` char(1) NOT NULL,
      `remote_addr` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      `first_visit_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `last_visit_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `customer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `last_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`visitor_id`),
      KEY `IDX_VISITOR_TYPE` (`visitor_type`),
      KEY `IDX_VISIT_TIME` (`first_visit_at`,`last_visit_at`),
      KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER` (`customer_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    TRUNCATE `report_event`;

    TRUNCATE `report_viewed_product_index`;

    TRUNCATE `report_compared_product_index`;

    TRUNCATE `dataflow_batch_export`;

    ALTER TABLE `orders` CHANGE `url` `parent_id` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;

Comment: My database size was around 52 MB in gunzip and 926 MB normal it took around 3 hrs to upgrade from v1.4 to V1.7.2

Comment: Point 6: where is “DB Changes.txt” ?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the most comprehensive description of the Magento 1.4 to 1.7.x upgrading is this way, offered by turnkey website:

Before proceeding with this part of Magento upgrade, it is important to see to what version Magento upgrade scripts will upgrade your store. Enter this command to check this:

```
1
./mage list-upgrades
```

If you will see this result:

```
Updates for community:
Mage_All_Latest: 1.4.2.1 => 1.7.0.2
Lib_Js_Mage: 1.4.2.0 => 1.7.0.2
Lib_Varien: 1.4.2.0 => 1.7.0.2
```

It means that your Magento will be upgraded to version 1.7.0.2. If it is not what you need you can change upgrade channel to “beta” and upgrade your Magento to RC (beta) version.

1 – Enter this command to change the upgrade channel to stable (remember, “stable” channel will upgrade your Magento to latest 1.7.x stable version):

```
1
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
```

After this the “./mage list-upgrades” command will show you this result:

Updates for community:

```
  Mage_All_Latest: 1.4.2.1 => 1.7.0.2.
    Lib_Js_Mage: 1.4.2.0 => 1.7.0.2.
    Lib_Varien: 1.4.2.0 => 1.7.0.2.
    Lib_Phpseclib: 1.4.2.0 => 1.7.0.2.
    Mage_Core_Adminhtml: 1.4.2.0 => 1.7.0.2.
    Mage_Core_Modules: 1.4.2.0 => 1.7.0.2.
```

2 – After channel selection you can upgrade your Magento to Magento 1.7.0.2) using this command:

```
1
./mage upgrade-all --force
```

If “./mage upgrade-all –force” will not work, you can try to execute this command:

```
1
./mage install connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

You will see upgraded packages on your screen:

```
…

    Package upgraded: community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.7.0.2
    Package upgraded: community/Lib_Mage 1.7.0.2
    Package upgraded: community/Lib_ZF 1.11.1.0
    Package upgraded: community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.7.0.2.
    Package upgraded: community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.11.1.0
```

Now the upgrade is complete and you can execute database upgrade visiting your Magento store in your browser, this process will take several minutes, so be patient. If everything was upgraded correctly, you will see upgraded store in your browser. Before database upgrade it is recommended to increase time and memory limits of your PHP engine.

If it is not possible to increase it, you can try to execute database upgrade via SSH, e.g.:

```
1

    php -f ./index.php
```

When database upgrade will be finished, you can check version of your store in the footer of Magento administration panel.

Answer (score 1):

Check your apache logs. However, it sounds like it's getting caught somewhere in the upgrade process. Make sure all your files are the new version, backup your database, and make sure your database connection information is correct.

You may also want to double check the size of your database. If your database is huge, magento may be timing out.

Comment: from mysql logs I found this error: 121031 11:25:49 [ERROR] Table magento17/sales_flat_order contains 9 indexes inside InnoDB, which is different from the number of indexes 8 defined in the MySQL

Answer (score 1):

How big is the current (1.4.0.1) database? Recently when I had to upgrade 7GB database it took whole weekend on local server - the reason of such long process is that version 1.6 has new indexers and the database structure was rebuild - installation scripts which are meant to be fired upon first load of updated code are droping lot of foreign keys and creating new ones with lot of constraints.

Comment: database backup size is about 210MB. As I mentioned there is an error in MySql erro log file. I think its stoping the upgrade process.
error: 121031 11:25:49 [ERROR] Table magento17/sales_flat_order contains 9 indexes inside InnoDB, which is different from the number of indexes 8 defined in the MySQL