# Magento export/import products

Tags: magento

I am having a problem exporting and importing products from Magento 1.4.1 to 1.9. What is the quickest and easiest way to do this? I cannot use the data profiles as i have a lot of configurable a in the site.

Comment: could you provide more detail - perhaps an example product object?

Comment: I have imported product in following ways [here][1]. It might be hepful.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163847/magento-upgrade-takes-too-long-and-never-completes/13194474#13194474

Comment: I used this extension to export/import it worked well http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-bulk-product-import-export-with-tier-pricing-product-custom-options-configurable-products-bundle-products-grouped-products-downloadable.html